# Azure Virtual Desktop - can't login

Tags: windows, azure, remote-desktop-services, entra-domain-services

I need to set up Azure Virtual Desktop and everything is deployed but there is no possibility to log in. Created the host pool, Desktop Application Group and a workspace, then added users to the DAG and gave them the "Desktop Virtualization User" IAM role in the application group resource.

My domain controller is hosted in Azure with Azure AD Domain Services. When I try to log in to the virtual desktop using the web client: https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html, I can log in via Microsoft, I can see the workspace and the session host, however when I enter my credentials, I get the error: `Sign in failed. Please check your username and password and try again.`

The credentials are fine - I've tried on multiple different accounts. Connecting using the Azure provided RDP client does not work as well. What am I missing here? I've followed dozens of tutorials, watched dozens of youtube videos on this topic and it seems so simple, yet in my case it is not working at all.

Comment: Sounds like your AVD hosts are not joining your domain correctly

Comment: They joined the domain - there were no "joinDomain" errors during the deployment and when I log in to the machine using the Administrator account and run the command "systeminfo" I can see that the host is in the correct domain.

Comment: Azure AD DS you say? hmm... did you reset the users passwords to generate password hashes that can be synced to Azure AD DS? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization#password-hash-synchronization-and-security-considerations

Comment: Did that as well.

Comment: i have the same issue - local account works fine but thats it.